# How to stick two arrays together in google sheets or excel?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Imagine I have two matrices. A:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

and B:

```
d 4
e 5
```

I want a function say "GLUE" to stick them together. I want something like

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(GLUE(A,B))
```

Which produces:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
```

These two matrices are produced dynamically (by a formula) and are nowhere in the sheet, so I need a "dynamic way" to glue them together.

---

Here is a concrete example. Suppose we have the following table:

```
Name  AGE     User      Developer
A      30     True      True
B      31     True      False
C      32     False     True
```

I need a list of users and developers that duplicate those that are both. So I can get the users with `=FILTER(A2:B4,C2:C4)` and the developers with `=FILTER(A2:B4,D2:D4)`. So ideally I could use `=ARRAYFORMULA(GLUE(FILTER(A2:B4,C2:C4),FILTER(A2:B4,D2:D4)))` (where GLUE is the function I need!) producing:

```
A      30
B      31
A      30
C      32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{A1:C3;A4:C5}` to glue them vertically. Use `,` or `\` to glue them horizontally[¹](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276). Unlike [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet), [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) however only supports glueing numbers/string literals and doesn't support cell references.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that if one of the matrices is empty, it adds an empty row.

Comment: Thank you, but filter forces me to write the formula twice. Does it not?